# How to print_string after read_string in RISC-V

Tags: riscv

I'm trying to read string save it to a registry than output. I'm getting the error "Source String must start at double word boundary when I try to do the following:

```
s1:    DC "Input a string"
       addi x30, x0, s1
       ecall x0, x30, 4 ;info string
       ecall x6, x0, 8 ;read_string
       ecall x0, x6, 4 ;info string //this is where there error is
```

I'm having a hard time finding any documentation on how to do this with RISC-V v0.46

Comment: What kind of RISC-V assembler is this? The `DC` directive looks unfamiliar to me.

Comment: It was called RVS (Risc-V Visual Simulator). DC (Define Characters): Accepts a single constant which must be a sequence of characters enclosed in double quotes. The ASCII codes of the characters are stored in one or more consecutive 64-bit double-words (8 characters per double-word) in increasing order of memory addresses. If necessary, the last double-word is padded with 0s. Include a trailing "\0" in the sequence of characters to make sure that it will be null-terminated irrespectively of its length. Note that the assembler will not automatically insert the terminating null character;

Comment: Ok - do you have a link? I can't seem to find it with google, today ...

Comment: Unfortunately no public facing one - seems that it was a proprietary learning software.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out I needed to load data into memory to read it, solved it as follows

```
s1:    DC "Input a string"
       addi x30, x0, s1
       ecall x0, x30, 4 ;info string
       ecall x6, x0, 8 ;read_string
       //load into memory
       sd x6, dst(x0)
       addi x29, x0, dst
       ecall x0, x29, 4 ;info string
dst:   DM 1
```